# PHP inside HTML - Importing API value

Tags: php, jquery, json, api

I'm having a hard time getting the "price" to be displayed. Am I using php the right way in this case?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%">
<td>Bitstamp</td>

<?php
$url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";
$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc, true);
$price = $json["last"];
?>

<td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. What do you get? Does your server support PHP? Does your filename end in .php ? Anything in your error log?

Comment: Your `<table>` is missing a row `<tr>` but I don't think it would stop it working

Comment: Everything you mentioned seems to be in order, but I get nothing. All I see is the "Bitstamp" text.

Comment: Please answer my previous questions about your server, filename and logs

Comment: There was a problem with Wordpress reading the file. Using "Insert PHP" plugin fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. If you don't get reply from file_get_contents function, you might want to set php setting allow_url_fopen=true

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen